# Child div element managing

Tags: javascript

```js
  var arrlength;//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function opentextarea(borderColor) { 
    
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("myCustomTextarea");
    arrlength=arr.length;
    
var goOut= 1;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr, function(el) {
   if (el.style.backgroundColor!=='lightblue'){
     goOut=0;
     alert("Enter or delete the previus commnet!"); 
   }
});
 if (goOut===1){
  //////////////
  
    var comentwindow = document.getElementById("StatusID"); //StatusID 
    var d1 = new Date();
    var d2= d1.toDateString();
    var d3= d1.toLocaleTimeString();
    var dateTimeUser = document.createTextNode(d2+" "+d3+" username");
    //dateTimeUser.style.fontSize = "8px";
    dateTimeUser.className = 'dateTimeUserClasN';
    dateTimeUser.id = arrlength+"dateTimeUserID";
    comentwindow.appendChild(dateTimeUser); /////////////////////////////////////////1
    
    var input = document.createElement('textarea');   
    input.maxLength = 5000;
    input.cols = 28;
    input.rows = 5;
    input.style.borderColor = borderColor;
    input.className = 'myCustomTextarea';
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("myCustomTextarea");
    input.id = arrlength+"textarea";
    //var comentwindow = document.getElementById("StatusID"); //StatusID 
    comentwindow.appendChild(input);//////////////////////////////////////////////////2
    
            
     var ele = document.getElementById(arrlength+"buttonSE");
     if(ele === null){ 
          var buttonSE = document.createElement('button');
          buttonSE.className = 'enterCommentBut';
          buttonSE.id=arrlength+"buttonSE";
         buttonSE.onclick = function() { 
              
             if(document.getElementById(arrlength+"textarea").value != ''){
            document.getElementById(arrlength+"textarea").style.backgroundColor= "lightblue";
             var e1 = document.getElementById('StatusID');
            var e2 =(e1.children.length);
            e1.removeChild(e1.children[e2-1]);
            e1.removeChild(e1.children[e2-2]);
             }else{
                 alert("It is not posible to enter empty comment.");
             }
         }
        var SE = document.createTextNode("Enter");       
        buttonSE.appendChild(SE);
        comentwindow.appendChild(buttonSE);/////////////////////////////////////////////3     
   }
  
  var ele2 = document.getElementById(arrlength+"buttonSC");
     if(ele2 === null){ 
          var buttonSC = document.createElement('button');
          buttonSC.className = 'clearCommentBut';
          buttonSC.id=arrlength+"buttonSC";
          buttonSC.onclick = function() { 
            var e1 = document.getElementById('StatusID');
            var e2 =(e1.children.length);
           
           var myNode = document.getElementById("StatusID");
            while (myNode.lastChild) {
            myNode.removeChild(myNode.lastChild);
          }    
         };
        var SC = document.createTextNode("Clear");       
        buttonSC.appendChild(SC);  
        comentwindow.appendChild(buttonSC);//////////////////////////////////////4
       }
  
    }
 }

  
function createObject2(){ 
     var e3 = document.getElementById("StatusID");
       var e4 = document.getElementById("Status0ID");
        var e5 = document.getElementById("Status2ID");
        
   
          e3.style.display = 'block';
          e4.style.display = 'block';
          e5.style.display = 'block';
}
document.getElementById("clickMe2").onclick = createObject2;



function updateScroll(){
    var element = document.getElementById("StatusID");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
   

function ObjectRed(){
 
  var borderColor= "red";
   opentextarea(borderColor);
   updateScroll();
  
}
document.getElementById("ObjectRed").onclick = ObjectRed;

function ObjectGreen(){
  
  var borderColor= "green";
   opentextarea(borderColor);
   updateScroll();
  
}
document.getElementById("ObjectGreen").onclick = ObjectGreen;
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



div.Status0 {
     position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    height:40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
   font-size: 12px;
   border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  background-color: white;
}

div.Status1 {
     position: absolute; 
    top: 70px;
    width: 250px;
    height:700px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  background-color: white;
}

div.Coment1{
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
 height:100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
 /* height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;*/
 border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  padding: 18px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #cfcfcf;
}


.myCustomTextarea {
border:0; 
padding:1px; 
font-size:1.0em; 
font-family:"Times New Roman";
color:black; 
border:solid 2px #ccc; 
margin:0 0 4px; 
width:215px;
height:50px;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
box-shadow: inner 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
-moz-border-radius: 3px; 
border-radius: 3px;
}

.myCustomTextarea:focus {
        resize: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        outline: none !important;
  }
   
.dateTimeUserClasN{
 
}
.startbutton{
     position: absolute; 
    left: 270px;
    top:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Custom </title> 

</head>
<body>
    <div class="Status0" id="Status0ID" style="display: none">
         <input type="button" id="ObjectRed" value="Problem" />
         <input type="button" id="ObjectGreen" value="Okay" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="Status2" id="Status2ID" style="display: none">
        <div class="Status1" id="StatusID" style="display: none"></div>
    </div>
           
    <input class =" startbutton" type="button" id="clickMe2" value="New object2"  /> 
             

 <script src="js/createObject.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleIvan.css">
</body>
</html>
```

I have a "div" inside main "div". Status1 inside Status2.  Status1 has a time date text, textarea and two buttons (enter and cancel).

When I call opentextarea function I get this 4 elements.

Below is this code for comments managing. The problem is that when i press on "cancel" button. It deletes all. But i would like to delete only last packet of
 4 elements (last Status1 div). I need Status1 to be child of Status2. So when i press on cancel to delete only last child.

I can not make this work for me, so I am asking here for help.

How to do it?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. I guess from what I read you have a problem deleting divs within divs. For this, there is a trick I learned to use, which is to create divs with a unique ID.

Comment: Please add your code to snippet then we can play with it.

Comment: As first pres on "newobject2"  Then you you may add comment by pressing on (problem or okay) buttons. In comment package you get timedate text, commenttext box and two button to enter comment or to cancel of actual comment. If you want one package to be entered you need to ad some text to textarea (at list one character) and then press on enter.

Comment: So let’s presume that after adding two comments (packages), you have change your mind and you do not want to add this comment any more. So you have to press on cancel. The case here is (and what I do not want ) all existing comments-packages will be deleted. And I want to make only last comment-package to be deleted. Pleas give me instructions how to do this. As you may see I have some programming experience, but i am still at the begging with web development.